# Trying to create nested multiple linear layout programmatically

Tags: android, dynamic, nested, android-linearlayout

I am trying to create nested linearlayouts dynamically and setting it to activity layout as 
`setContentView(createLayout());` in `oncreate()`.
But I am getting nothing on the screen but a blank screen. Can someone help in pointing out if I am doing it in wrong way?

```
   private LinearLayout createLayout() {
    Log.d(TAG,"calling cretaelayout");
    LinearLayout main = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    int k =0;
    for(int i=0 ;i < MainActivity.height*10;i++) {
        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        for(int j=0;j< MainActivity.width*10;j++)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"creating layout element");
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            ll.setId( k++);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            ll.setLayoutParams(new     LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            ll.setOnClickListener(myhandler);
            row.addView(ll);
        }
        main.addView(row);
    }

    return main;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing anywhere that takes space.  You have a LL inside an LL inside an LL, with the last LL set to wrap_content.  But it has no content inside it, so its size will be 0 in both directions.  Elements with no size don't appear.  Try making the inner most LLs fixed size, and you should see something.